# How to get ffmpeg to fail if stdin stream has errors?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got some code that outputs rawvideo to ffmpeg via pipe, which then overlays a png over it. If the code exits with an error, ffmpeg keeps going forever, I don't know how to stop it :( Any ideas? Here's an example:

```
set -o pipefail

(echo "error!!"; exit 1) | \
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -c:v rawvideo -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt bgra -i - \
    -i my_icon.png \
    -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=50:50" \
    out.mp4
```

Note ffmpeg DOES show an error message, but still does not stop, stuck in 'frame 0' forever, with a strange time attribute e.g. `time:-577014:32:22.77`:

```
    [rawvideo @ 0x563fc94427c0] Packet too small (8)
    Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
    Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it.:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
    frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
```

ffmpeg version information as requested in comments:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.2-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu2)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
```

Comment: It exists when I run your example command. What version of ffmpeg are you using?

Comment: @szatmary I updated the question with version info

Comment: @szatmary I also tried updating to the latest 3.4.6 (it's on ubuntu 18.04 docker)

Comment: @szatmary I now tried with ffmpeg4.2 and indeed it seems as if it stops, but in fact, if I replace the png with some long audio file, I see that it simply processes the audio file until it's complete and doesn't stop. It was not so observable with a png because it completes quickly.